# How can I get progress info from a java ee 7 batch

Tags: batch-processing, java-ee-7

I am working with java ee 7 batch and - from a different thread of execution - would like to retrieve info on the progress of the job. I know I can always retrieve the job execution but I would like more detailed info, such as how many records have been processed.

Is there a way to feed this information back into the batch framework during processing so that I could retrieve it in the other thread? As far as I've seen I cannot update the job properties during processing.

Thanks, regards,
gufi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch API does not mandate any progress monitoring but it is really easy to roll your own - have a look at [batch listeners](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/batch/batch-listeners) - that way you have access to all phases of batch execution(read, process, write) and you can just plug in some custom reporting - e.g. update the job values in DB, or send them via JMS to some listener or websocket  or anything you like.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.